# What is the relation between$ P(A|B)$ and $P(A|B')$ for both independent and not independent events?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events.
If they are independent, how are $P(A|B)$ and $P(A'|B)$ related, if at all?
If they are not independent, how are $P(A|B)$ and $P(A'|B)$ related, if at all?

I've noticed the notation my book uses might be a little dated so just to clarify:
-- $A'$ is the complement of $A$ 
-- $P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ given $B$.

Comment: The notation is pretty standard, but your title and question do not match up.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are independant, $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and $P(A'|B)=P(A')$. So you have $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A'|B)$. It remains true without independance.

But you can't say anything about $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|B')$.